# PARITY using depth one TC0 circuit

Tags: complexity-theory, complexity-classes, circuits

I need to disprove that a `PARITY` gate can be simulated using a **single** `MAJORITY` gate, or even a `THRESHOLD` gate. How do I go about doing this? Some ideas as to how to go about contradiction or otherwise would be helpful.

One possible argument would be monotonicity of `MAJORITY` and `THRESHOLD` while `PARITY` is non-monotone (Page 134 of [this paper](http://www.igi.tugraz.at/psfiles/47.pdf)). But, I do not find this sufficiently convincing.

Comment: Are you only allowed to use one threshold gate, and nothing else?

Comment: Since it is a depth one $TC^0$ circuit, we can use only one `MAJORITY` or `THRESHOLD` gate and `NOT` gates.

Comment: Here's a hint/simplification. Let's suppose you can do that for some $n>2$, then you can fix all inputs except two to zero. Now you have a circuit with two inputs that computes $PARITY(x,y)$. Try to show even this is impossible.